# Jquery- get same value in different items

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

i have a dropdown list like this

```
<?php echo form_open('cart/add');?>
    <select id="color">
     <option value="1">1 </option>
     <option value="2">2 </option>
     <option value="3">3 </option>
     <option value="4">4 </option>
    </select>
// other input form 
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

and the javascript looks like this

```
var e = "url of the site";
$("ul.wipproducts form").submit(function () {
    var t = $(this).find("input[name=id]").val();
    var n = $(this).find("input[name=quantity]").val();
    var x = $("#color option:selected").text();
    $.post(e + "cart/add", {
        id: t,
        quantity: n,
        color: x,
        ajax: "1"
    }, function (t) {
        if (t == "true") {
            $.get(e + "cart/show_cart", function (e) {
                $("#main").html(e);
            })
        } else {
            alert("failed");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

i wanted to get the item color from different item in the same category
example:
i added item A with color red
and then i added item B with color blue in the same category
but in the cart page, the color of item B is red instead of blue.

any idea?

Comment: michael zalla: thanks for the edit

Comment: What's the usage of `post` and `get`? If callback of `get` is for **Add item with color X** and `$("#main").html(e);` is the only code to change your html, so how can it get different results with a same url of `get`?

Comment: @Dylengleng get callback is used to be in the same page without refreshing/redirecting the page after i add items.

Answer (score 0):

On form submit, to retrieve the value of `x`, you can just use:

```
var x = $('#color').val();
```

If that is not the issue, you can check the console on your browser to make sure that the correct values are getting sent. Your callback function looks like it is retrieving the list of all cart items, so without looking at the `show_cart` code, I am guessing that the data is stored incorrectly.

Comment: doesn't work.. it returned all of the values in the <option></option>
not the selected option, thanks anyway